# What is a hex editor?

Tags: binary, hex, editor

What is the purpose of a hex editor? Is it a programming language like C or Python and how can I learn to program in it? Also, is there any way to code in binary? I read an autobiography about Steve Jobs, and at one point I think one of his co-workers had to write a program in binary, and it seemed like a pretty cool thing to learn how to do. There is no real-world problem for me to solve, I am just curious. I have a very basic understanding of computers, so pretend like you are explaining this to a 5th grader.

Comment: It just lets you edit the numeric contents of a file directly. So, for example, if it's a text file, you're looking at the ASCII codes for the text, not the text itself. Just google "Hex editor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most programming languages we use are on a high level, in the sense that they are translated several times before machines can actually recognize it. Your CPU actually executes very simple instructions, coded by 0's and 1's, like add, logical or, load a number from memory address into register (so we can add or manipulate the value), etc.

So how does this translation work? Well suppose you've written a simple hello world program in C. It needs to be translated to the machine code, in what is called compiling process. During this stage, your code is translated into an intermediate language based on your specific CPU, the assembly. This is supposed to be humanly readable machine instructions (the previously mentioned add, load, etc). Then the machine instruction is further translated into 0's and 1's.

For example, add in MIPS CPU architecture looks like:

```
0000 0000 0010 0010 0001 1000 0010 0000
```

Which basically says, add the values stored in register 1 and 2, and put the result in register 3.

The thing is quite long, so we usually write it not in binary, but in hex. Four 0's and 1's compress into a digit, and we get:

```
00 22 19 20
```

So when you open an executable in a hex editor, all these values comprises of instructions like above, static data, libraries and such. When you edit these values, suppose you know what you are doing, you can change the behavior of the software.

However, you do not want to write a program in binary. It is quite painful. I'd recommend looking at assembly and how CPU's work, if you are more interested.

Some advantages you might get over writing in machine code than C:

1. You get more flexibility with what you can do. You can manage your resources with the whole program in mind, so you can optimize everything. Some time sensitive instruments on aircrafts are written in assembly.
2. You get a comprehensive understanding on exactly how every part of the program works.

And the drawbacks:

1. It is extremely hard to keep so many things in mind at once. It is very error prone, and very hard to debug.
2. It is extremely time consuming. You are about 1/10th productive writing in assembly, and so even worse in machine code since you need to look up operation code translations.
3. It is not platform independent. Machine code is per CPU architecture so your code for windows (x86 architecture) is not going to work on Mac, while a C program can just be recompiled and run instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Most executables are **binary files** in a system. Examining binary content can be important sometimes, but reading large files with only 0's and 1's is a pretty tedious task. The idea is that each bloc of four 0's and 1's can be represented by one **hexadecimal symbol** : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , A , B, C, D, E, F. The hex editor will facilitate the task of reading binary content of any kind (files or tcp frames on a network for example). But note that even in hexadecimal, you need a good computer knowledge to understand the file contents.

Comment: But what advantage does it have over a language like C?

Comment: humans don't write computer programs in binary, they use C, Java, Python or Assembly language. Binary is not a programming language. The purpose of an Hex Editor is only to analyse binary content more easily, sometimes to  modify it slightly, that's all